# Indefinite integral of reciprocal n degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I find that the Torricelli's trumpet has very interesting properties.

It's surface:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2\pi}{x}dx=2\pi\ln{x}|_{1}^{\infty}\rightarrow\infty.$$

is infinity.

Its volume:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}{x^{2}}dx=-\frac{\pi}{x}|_{1}^{\infty}=\pi.$$

is finite.

I extend it so its radius will be:

$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+c}},c\ is\ a\ constant.$$

Its surface will be:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{x^2+c}}dx=2\pi\ln \left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+x^2}{c}}\right||_1^\infty\rightarrow\ diverges.$$

Then its volume:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}{x^2+c}dx=\frac{\pi ^2}{2\sqrt{c}}-\frac{\pi \arctan \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}\right)}{\sqrt{c}}\rightarrow\ converges.$$

I tried to extend further for the radius:

$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+c}}.\\$$

Its surface:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\ \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+c}} dx.\\$$

Its volume:
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty}\ \frac{\pi}{(x^3+c)^{2/3}} dx.\\$$

I can't find a general formula for

$$\int_\ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+c}} dx.\\$$

If c is polynomial and its degree will be less then the x term before it.

How would I do a general expression for:

$$\int_\ \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\cdots+z}} dx.\\$$

Comment: It's not an elementary function, you'll need elliptic integrals for that.

Comment: @John He -  It seems this is your first post. On MSE, it is required to provide context and background to your question and to speak to whatever methods you have employed (and provide the detail of that). If you haven't tried anything, you must be upfront and ask for a starting point. Make sure you tag the 'Soft Question' tag when you do so. 

It seems over the top when you first start on the site, but over time you come to realise that it's a great system. 

Please message me if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General indefinite integrals of the form
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0}}, \qquad a_n \neq 0,$$
do not have closed forms when $n > 2$.

For the particular integral $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 + c}} ,$$ however, substituting $$x^3 = \frac{c}{1 - u^3}$$ gives
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 + c}} = \int \frac{u \,du}{1 - u^3} ,$$
which can be handled by standard techniques.

On the other hand, as $x \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0}}$ is comparable (for $n > 0$) to $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}} \frac{1}{x},$$ and so the definite integrals of the form $$\int_M^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0}}$$ arising in the surface area computations all diverge.